# Adobe inDesign file/project sometimes opens as readonly on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-indesign

I have iMac with MacOS + Adobe InDesign.

And sometimes when I double click InDesign file/project it opens up as read-only and I don't see it until I try to save it and I can't so I have to save as new file. It sometimes leads to problems in the future.

But its not always the case. Usually it opens up normally, but sometimes as read-only.

We have these files on qnap. Shared drive among us, graphic designers. The files may be from someone else. But sometimes it opens as read-only and sometimes normally. And sometimes read-only even if I am sure no one else work on these files right know. Maybe permission issue but strange to me.

Why is that? Is this some known case? I really do not know what to think about it.

Comment: Does this happen with projects/files you receive from someone else, or also with the ones you created yourself, and previously opened as editable? If it's only on projects received from others, it's most likely a permission issue, [check and change as necessary](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac).

Comment: @Peregrino69 We have these files on qnap. Shared drive among us, graphic designers. The files may be from someone else. But sometimes it opens as read-only and sometimes normally. And sometimes read-only even if I am sure no one else work on these files right know. Maybe permission issue but strange to me.